How to create a sign pdf web application like ilovepdf sign-pdf using PDF-LIB?
I have a Laravel website. I need a pdf viewer that can also add handwritten signatures.
I found PDF-LIB as a pdf editor. But the website only explains how to edit using hard code.
I need a user interface for the editor, for example the website https://www.ilovepdf.com/sign-pdf. But I have no idea how to make it.
So, how do I make it?

HTML5 provides a canvas element that you can have users draw on. Use JavaScript to place lines over wherever the user moves the mouse while the left button is held down or the like. https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_canvas.asp
